# C# Regex match commas and decimals

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying regex to match decimals and commas. Code will take Bitcoin wallet account balance from API, what example would be `0.003827385,` How could regex match number like that?

Comment: What is format of your numbers ? Are they comma separated or simple decimal numbers ? Because the given answer won't be correct if your format is having many many numbers .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do it:

```
 Regex.Match(SearchString,"[0-9]+\.?[0-9,]*");
```

https://regex101.com/r/fP5jI7/2

Comment: wow, I am stupid :D, I tried like Huge piece of codes :D Thank You!

Comment: The other code worked as well tho, can't accept answer yet. You answered too fast, I have to wait a bit

Comment: the other answer works but it will match single comma and single . too, but  this one will match dots and comma if it is used in a number

Comment: It also matches `0.003.827.385,`. I guess that's not a valid number.

Comment: Got one more problem tho, How could I "convert" number to smaller one? 

I got number: 0.00236082912318806 -> 18 different numbers
Maximum for me would be: 9 numbers, how could I do it example it's gonna take last 9 numbers away?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try a regex to match decimals?

```
([\d+[,\d]*]*\.\d+)|[\d+[,\d]*]*
```

Your question is not clear about usage of commas. Note the above regex will not match commas after decimal point.

Comment: *but commas are generally not used after the decimal point* may be legit in en culture, but dots can be group separators and commas decimal separator (ie de).

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - didn't know that. Will edit the answer.