# Optional group in regex is merged into the required greedy group that follows it

Tags: regex

I have a line that looks like this

```
      2 Oct             POST   1.27                                   2,544
```

I want to grab each of these into their own regex groups

So i tried this

```
(?<Date>2\s(Oct))?\s*?(?<Req>.*?)\s*(?<Time>\d{0,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d\d)\s+(?<Time2>\d{0,3}(,\d{3}))?
```

But the `Req` group captures the `Date` as well
For example, `Req` is the following

```
          2 Oct             POST
```

And `Date` never shows up.

Here is the example
https://regex101.com/r/xMhIp5/1

`Date` is supposed to be day and month, but I'm just simplifying things here. Also, the date is optional. But Req is not.

How do I prevent `Req` from grabbing the date part.  Technically `Req` is everything between the date and the `Time` group.

Thanks

Comment: Try the following: `^\s*(?<DayOfMonth>\d{1,2})\s*(?<Month>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s*(?<HttpMethod>(POST|GET){1}?)\s*(?<Version>\d{1,2}.\d+)\s*(?<Size>[0-9]+,?[0-9]*)` References: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957683/c-sharp-regex-match-commas-and-decimals) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: Are you sure you need regexes here? `string.Split` will do the work 10 times simpler and faster.

Comment: You have made the Date group optional with `?` so you can remove the question mark if it is not optional.

Comment: Is date obligatory or optional? Now, it seems it is not.

Comment: The date is optional

Comment: `(?<Date>\d+\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s*(?<Req>.*?)\s*(?<Time>\d{0,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d\d)\s+(?<Time2>\d{0,3}(,\d{3}))?`? I saved as a new demolink, https://regex101.com/r/xMhIp5/2

Comment: This won’t work if the date is optional.

Comment: Please post more sample data. One line of data is insufficient for proper testing - particularly when some of the data is optional.

Comment: See [update](https://regex101.com/r/xMhIp5/3).

Comment: If the date is optional, try the following: `^\s*((?<DayOfMonth>\d{1,2})\s*(?<Month>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)))?\s*(?<HttpMethod>(POST|GET){1}?)\s*(?<Version>\d{1,2}.\d+)\s*(?<Size>[0-9]+,?[0-9]*)`